# How to send cookie in flutter graphql calls

Tags: flutter, cookies, graphql

I am working on an Graphql QUERY API which reads domain cookies and based on that return data but when working on flutter app I am not able to send cookies(Which is default in browser). Is there an easier way to send cookies.

Below is my code snippet for Reading cookies from domain. I think there should be some way to set cookies/options in httpLink somehow.

```
    final cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();
    final gotCookies = await cookieManager.getCookies('https://someApp.com');
    
    final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
        uri: 'https://someApp.com/graphql',
        includeExtensions: true
    );
    
    ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
       GraphQLClient(
         cache: InMemoryCache(),
         link: httpLink,
       ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this. We can set cookie in headers just like below and it works.

```
HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
        uri: 'https://apps.cloudhealthtech.com/ui-session',
        headers: {'Cookie': 'session_id=ctHB0ZewfasKWBWIUu;'});
```

Comment: Where do you get the session Id from?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to pass Browser cookies along GraphQL requests without retrieving them first. It uses the Browser client

```
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
```

Insert a prepared Http client into the httpLink

```
  var myClient = BrowserClient();
  myClient.withCredentials =true;
  final httpLink = HttpLink(endpoint +"/graphql",
    httpClient: myClient,
    // ...
  );
```